# How to convert a string to camel case in Mule 4

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-esb, mulesoft, mule4

Is there any function to convert a string ex: "iamhuman" to camel case "iAmHuman" in Mule 4 application.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `camelize` function you can use in dataweave. **BUT** it will **NOT** work with your example because it won't know where the word breaks are. If you had another separator, such as underscores or hyphens then this would work:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Strings
output application/json
---
{ "camelize" : camelize("i_am_human") }
```